# JavaScript remove element from memory

Tags: javascript, dom, memory

I'm trying to do something like limitless scrolling at Facebook. Everything was good but after loading more than 200 posts my browser crashed out (of course it's obvious, I run out of memory). After reading some threads here I'm little bit consused.

My code looks like

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^=mall_post]");
elements[0].remove();
delete elements[0];
```

I don't know how to solve it. As I know as GC will delete it if there won't be any references, but how to check which part of code is pointing for it?

Answer (score 0):

Take heap snapshots using chrome developer tools and you can see what can be optimised and what objects are being referenced.

Comment: But how I can figure where is my desired div?

Comment: did you try analyzing a heap dump from dev tools?